# how to add preprocess loader in webpack 2

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, preprocessor, webpack-plugin

I am trying to add preprocess loader in my webpack 3. I have installed it successfully. but it is not working
here's my webconfing file

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/app.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader!preprocess-loader?+DEBUG',
        // query: {
        //   presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
        //   plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        // }
      },
      {
       test: /\.css$/,
       loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"

    }

    ] 

    },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "demo.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "snapstrat-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sephore project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "prod": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.12.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "preprocess-loader": "^0.2.2",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

below my index.html. I am following this github [read me](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess#options)

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

      <!-- @exclude -->
    <header>You're on dev!</header>
    <!-- @endexclude -->

  </body>
```

Comment: How are you using the `index.html`? If you don't import it somehow in webpack, it won't process it at all, additionally you only defined the `preprocess-loader` for `.js(x)` files, HTML files won't be affected. Should you only want to use it for the `index.html`, you might be better off using [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) with a custom [EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs) template.

Comment: @MichaelJungo: actually I want to use it for js(x) files. I just started trying with HTML file